# DataTable attached to SQL Database with function in query not automatically updating

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, data-binding, datagridview

I am trying to bind my Datagridview to a SQL Database. When I update the database from another source (from the SQL Query in Visual Stuido) the changes aren't shown in the DataGridView or the underlying DataTable.

I'm running my program, populating the DataGridView with essentially the function below and then changing the database using a SQL query from visual studio. The DataGridView doesn't update and the DataTable doesn't fire the RowChanged event!

```
_query = "SELECT * FROM myFunction(0) ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
_connection = new SqlConnection("working connection string");
_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_query, _connection);
_cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(_adapter);

_table = new DataTable();
_table.RowChanged += _table_RowChanged;

_adapter.Fill(_table);

_bindingSource = new BindingSource();
_bindingSource.DataSource = table;
_dataGridView.DataSource = _bindingSource;

// DataGridView is now populated

// run sql query externally from the program
// to update one of the rows/columns that the above function will return

// never updates datagridview and never updates the row in dataTable
```

I think that the problem is something to do with the function, does the adapter constantly poll the database with the query? If it doesn't I can see that it can't tell that it's updated.

Comment: Bind gridview after the datasource

Comment: Not sure what you mean, DGV is being bound to the BindingSource after the table.

Comment: thanks for your help, but there is no DataBind() method for windows forms datagridview: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/2639235d-82ff-4946-ba95-3c0ee117544d/why-there-is-no-databind-method-for-datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have read this correctly, you have a databound DataGridView who's DataSource is a DataTable. You have changed the actual database's table with some SQL programmatically, and are expecting to see an update in the DataGridView. That's not going to fly, pal. After updating the actual database, you should refresh the data source, by casting it to a DataTable and refilling it with a SqlDataAdapter using the same SQL you used to fill it the first time.  Updating the actual database will not be reflected in your data source, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have tried adding an "Update" button that just runs _adapter.Fill(_table); but this doesn't see that the database has updated either. If I execute that entire block of code in the OP again it will see that it has updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an [[example](http://pastebin.com/E1vp4w7t)] I just coded up really quick. It's after midnight and I have work in the morning. But you should get the idea. This is as simple as it gets, set the datasource of the datagridview and just refresh it explicitly by giving it a new datatable. And the line that actually sets the datasource could be extracted into a separate FillData() method. The query can be stored in a string var instead of being hardcoded twice. Really sloppy but it works. :P

Comment: Okay, so my idea is to poll the database on a background worker and then publish any changes to the DataTable. Is there a good way to do this? Or a way to compare DataTables to see if they differ?

Comment: Good question. Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) about the SqlDependency class which will let you know when the database changes. No need to poll. :]